# php version_compare() fails on localhost, runs on server

Tags: php, compare, version

This conditional code execution if statement is right out of the php manual:

```
// version_compare ( string $version1 , string $version2 [, string $operator ] )
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') >= 0)
{
    //echo 'I am at least PHP version 5.3.0, my version: ' . PHP_VERSION . "\n";
    include_once( DOMAIN_PATH . "sitewide/functions/make_comparer.php" );
    usort($market_and_volume, make_comparer(['exchange_volume', SORT_DESC], ['exchange', SORT_DESC]));   
}
```

The above code runs free of error on the production server. On localhost php version 5.2.9-2 which theoretically fails the version_compare() function it throws an error:

Parse error: parse error, expecting `')'' in test.php on line 61

Normally i might not care since its running on the 5.4.39 production server, however I plan to use this snippet on almost every localhost page which as it stands would impede future development.

Any ideas?

Comment: What line is 61? Can you confirm it is the if statement?

Comment: its your short array syntax its not supported on localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using the shorthand array notation. `[...]`.  Unfortuantely this is only supported from PHP 5.4.0 and up.  Even though the "bad" code is never run it fails to compile so throws an error.

This can be fixed by using the `array(...)` notation like so.

```
// version_compare ( string $version1 , string $version2 [, string $operator ] )
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') >= 0)
{
    //echo 'I am at least PHP version 5.3.0, my version: ' . PHP_VERSION . "\n";
    include_once( DOMAIN_PATH . "sitewide/functions/make_comparer.php" );
    usort($market_and_volume, make_comparer(array('exchange_volume', SORT_DESC), array('exchange', SORT_DESC)));   
}
```

REFERENCE: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: MarshallOfSound & Dagon are correct there is no error with alternate array notation. Thank you both.